# Android Cloud Test Lab vs Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, automated-tests, google-cloud-test-lab

I could not find a link that tells its difference. I know that the former is Google's own test lab. Then theres Firebase and I heard that Google recently acquired them. So are they the same now? or still totally different department?

Comment: I think you can clear watching video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSdKZqJ73a8   and      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNPCgJW8c-E

Comment: have u seen the videos you posted? They do not answer my question

Answer (score 3):

It seems the former became the latter

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-test-lab-external/0VYkA5INlJs